# How to apply custom headers/footers on pages with new chapters?

Tags: header-footer, chapters, fancyhdr

I'm writing my final report in LaTeX for my bachelor's degree. I'm aiming at having a document similar to the .doc template used normally.

I want to have my customs headers and footers applied on pages when I'm starting a new chapter.

I'm using documentclass `report` with `fancyhdr` and `lastpage` packages.

My headers are defined like this:

```
\lhead{\myTitle}
\rhead{\today}
\cfoot{\thepage\ of \pageref{LastPage}}
```

My chapters are created using standard `\chapter{title}` macro.

On pages with new chapters, the only headers/footers I see is the standard page number at the bottom.

What should I do?

EDIT: I've finally gone with Peter Breitfeld's solution. I'Ve gone a step further and created my own chapter command:

```
\newcommand{\myChapter}[1]{
    \chapter{#1}
    \thispagestyle{fancy}
}
```

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

LaTeX by default switches to `\pagestyle{plain}` on pages with `\chapter{...}`. You have to overwrite this:

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{lastpage}

\pagestyle{fancy}  

\lhead{myTitle}
\rhead{\today}

\begin{document}

\chapter{Introduction}
\thispagestyle{fancy}    %% <---- switch
some Text

\newpage
 some more text


\end{document}
```

Comment: You should better redefine the plain pagestyle as described in the documentation of fancyhdr